# Using toolchain file for different build host

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I want to adopt CMake for builds in a controlled build environment but will not be able to install CMake on these systems. I have seen resources detailing how to cross compile using a toolchain file (https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling).

Would it be possible to use this technique to run CMake on one system to build makefiles to be used on a different build host? Are there any resource available detailing any pitfalls? I will be generating makefiles on Linux for many platforms from Arm Linux to z/OS.

Comment: Two comments: For one "Cross-Compiling" for CMake means there has to be the "Cross-Compiler" installed on your PC/OS running CMake to generate the environment. So no, you can't generate something for another PC/OS environment. The second thing is, you don't need to install CMake. It's self-contained and can run e.g. from a source control image.

Comment: @Florian Yes what I am describing is not "cross-compiling". I'd like to avoid trying to build CMake on a very old versions of Z/OS and AIX if I can avoid it. There seems to be mentions of flag to turn of host environment checks when cross-compiling which is why I thought it might be closely related.

Comment: Even if that would be possible, you can't move CMake generated build trees somewhere else. See [CMake's FAQ: Why does CMake use full paths, or can I copy my build tree?](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_use_full_paths.2C_or_can_I_copy_my_build_tree.3F)

Comment: @Florian That answers my question, I'd accept that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

1. "Cross-Compiling" for CMake means there has to be the "Cross-Compiler" installed on your PC/OS running CMake to generate the environment.

   So no, you can't generate e.g. makefiles for another PC/OS environment.
2. You can't move CMake generated build trees somewhere else.

   See [CMake's FAQ: Why does CMake use full paths, or can I copy my build tree?](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_use_full_paths.2C_or_can_I_copy_my_build_tree.3F)

*Note:* You don't need to install CMake. It's self-contained and can run e.g. from a source control image. So you don't need to have administrative rights to run CMake.